# Query between 2 columns (Quantity Tier)

Tags: mysql

I have data in DB like this

```
Price_Per_Item | Min_Qty | Max_Qty
------------------------------------
    10.00      |    1    |   10 
    20.00      |    10   |   20  
    30.00      |    20   |   30  
    40.00      |    30   |   NULL
```

I put `NULL` is for more than 30 because don't have maximum quantity.

So I using this query is working for `Max_Qty` that don't have `NULL` but not working if have `NULL`

```
SELECT Price_Per_Item FROM price WHERE '100' BETWEEN Min_Qty AND Max_Qty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(price_per_item DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Min_Qty INT NOT NULL
,Max_Qty INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10.00,1,10),
(20.00,10,20),
(30.00,20,30),
(40.00,30,NULL);

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE min_qty < 100 
   AND (max_qty > 100 OR max_qty IS NULL);
+----------------+---------+---------+
| price_per_item | Min_Qty | Max_Qty |
+----------------+---------+---------+
|          40.00 |      30 |    NULL |
+----------------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
SELECT Price_Per_Item FROM price WHERE '100' BETWEEN Coalesce(Min_Qty,'100') AND Coalesce(Max_Qty,'100')

Let's first look at the rules of comparing nulls:

- NULL = NULL evaluates to unknown
- NULL <> NULL evaluates to unknown
- value = NULL evaluates unknown
- unknown  AND  true   = unknown
- unknown  AND  false  = false
- unknown  OR   true   = true
- unknown  OR   false  = unknown

`'100' BETWEEN Min_Qty AND Max_Qty` gets interpreted as `'100' >= Min_Qty AND '100' <= Max_Qty`

In this case when `Max_Qty` is `null`, `'100' <= Max_Qty` evaluates to unknown.

`'100' >= Min_Qty AND Unknown` can only return `unknown` or `false`.

Using coalesce will take the first not null variable in the list.

Comment: You can compare on NULL. It's just a very specific kind of comparison.

Comment: Also '100' is a string, but this is really a numeric comparison.

Comment: @Strawberry OP did not mentioned about the column data type, using string here could be safer as it is being casted implicitly, there'll be error if the underlying datatype is string and you compare it against an number.

Answer (score -1):

You can't compare null values with your provided values so you have to put your value in coalesce for comparing. For Example :-

SELECT *
FROM products
where 100 between Min_Qty and COALESCE(Max_Qty,100);

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of an existing answer.